# Gii module's view

Tags: php, yii, gii

When I generate a CRUD for a model in a context of a module using Gii tool I expect views and controller be created under module directory but they be created under application controller and view direction. Why and How can I fix it?

Here is my model path alias

```
application.modules.admin.models.SysMessage
```

clarification:

controller and views be created here:

```
/controller
/views
```

but it should be created here:

```
/modules/admin/controller
/modules/admin/views
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the correct controller id 
admin/sysMessage